# LiNQ using ThenBy after OrderBy

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq, sql-order-by

I have a collection and number of OrderBy statemensts which sorts using query.Sort parameter

```
switch (filters.Sort)
{
    case "new":
        query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedAt);
        break;
    case "old":
        query = query.OrderBy(a => a.CreatedAt);
        break;
    case "salary-asc":
        query = query.OrderBy(a => a.Profile.CompensationTypeRate.FromCompensation);
}
```

Now I need to apply another sort using a `query.Grade` parameter. I know I should be using `ThenBy` to have multiple Order statements, but in this case I cannot write it in one line.

Is there a way to write `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` so they are executed one by one, and not in one line?

Or can I create some anonymous function that contains my `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` conditions ?

Comment: Daisy's answer is correct. It's worth pointing out you can chain IEnumerables together like this in all sorts of situations. The chain won't be executed until the IEnumerable is evaluated, like in a for each loop, or in a ToList() invocation.

Comment: @VictorWilson: I'll mention that in my answer, thanks.

Comment: Note that separate variable is not required, you can just cast: `((IOrderedQueryable<Employee>) query).ThenBy(...)`. You can also check IF query is `IOrderedQueryable<Employee>` and if yes - apply `ThenBy`, otherwise apply regular `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in two parts if you use a variable of type `IOrderedQueryable<T>` - that's what enables `ThenBy`. For example:

```
IOrderedQueryable<Application> ordered;

switch (filters.Sort)
{
    case "new":
        ordered = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedAt);
        break;
    case "old":
        ordered = query.OrderBy(a => a.CreatedAt);
        break;
    case "salary-asc":
        ordered = query.OrderBy(a => a.Profile.CompensationTypeRate.FromCompensation);
    default:
        // You need to work out what you want to do here. Maybe just
        // order by ID? You need to order by *something* to start with
        // in order to use ThenBy
}

// Apply the same secondary ordering, regardless of the primary one
ordered = ordered.ThenBy(x => x.Grade);

// You can then continue to use ordered, or assign the value back
// to query:
query = ordered;
```

Note that all of this will still be lazy. The ordering won't actually *happen* until you try to use the results.

Comment: the type of query variable is IQueryable<Application> query; where Application is just a class. How can I cast it or declare it as IOrderedQueryable<Application> ?

Comment: @Jalle: You don't change `query` - you introduce a new variable of type `IOrderedQueryable<Application>`, as I've done in my example.